# Running headless_chrome in a Dockerized Rust Lambda function

Tags: docker, rust, aws-lambda, selenium-chromedriver, serverless

I'm trying to run [headless_chrome](https://crates.io/crates/headless_chrome) in a dockerized lambda function.

My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM rust:1.75.0-alpine3.19 as build

ARG binary

RUN apk update \
    && apk add --no-cache build-base pkgconfig libressl-dev
WORKDIR /usr/src/api-service
COPY src/ src/
COPY Cargo.toml Cargo.toml
RUN cargo install --bin ${binary} --path .


FROM alpine:3.19
RUN apk update

# Install chromium and chromedriver
RUN apk add --no-cache bash chromium chromium-chromedriver
ENV PATH="$PATH:/usr/bin/chromedriver"

ENV CHROME_BIN=/usr/bin/chromium-browser \
    CHROME_PATH=/usr/lib/chromium/


WORKDIR /usr/src/app

ARG binary
ARG log_level
ARG stage
ENV RUST_LOG=${log_level}
ENV STAGE=${stage}
COPY --from=build /usr/local/cargo/bin/${binary} /asset-output/bootstrap

ENTRYPOINT [ "/asset-output/bootstrap" ]
```

This is the Rust part:

```
        use headless_chrome::{Browser, LaunchOptions};

        tracing::debug!("Creating browser");
        let options = LaunchOptions::default_builder()
            .headless(true)
            .sandbox(false)
            .window_size(Some((1920, 1080)))
            .build()
            .expect("Couldn't find appropriate Chrome binary.");
        tracing::debug!("Creating browser");
        let browser = Browser::new(options)?;
        tracing::debug!("Creating tab");
        let tab = &browser.new_tab()?;

        tracing::debug!("Fetching {}", &url);
        tab.navigate_to(&url).expect("failed to navigate");
```

Running the lambda shows that it gets stuck during the browser creation step. This are the logs:

```
...
DEBUG Creating browser
thread 'main' panicked at src/import/import.rs:23:19:
Trying to work with closed connection 
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace 
...
```

The backtrace, when enabled, doesn't give much info either.

I tried running the docker image locally and it works fine there. That's why I believe it might be a lambda environment specific behaviour. What am I missing?